# What does pressure rating of pumps mean?

Tags: pressure, pumps

So I am thinking of purchasing a [double motor pump](https://geekguider.com/product/agriansh-12v-dc-water-pump-battery-sprayer-motor-double-high-performance-12v-dc-220-psi/) for higher flow rates. This pump is available in two pressure ratings, 150PSI and 220PSI. What does it mean? I read that it means how much resistance it can face. I am not expecting to provide any resistance while it is on except the resistance in piping walls. Does it matter whether I buy 150PSI or 220PSI? I just need a pump that would fill my 1 Ltr bottle in less than a 10 seconds.

It also says cutoff pressure is 10.3bar. What does that mean?

Comment: Resistance can also be due to head ie change in height.

Comment: @SolarMike If I have the pump on a table and the source on the ground, would that constitute as resistance? would it be able to pull?

Comment: That would be a measurement of head like 1m. But all pumps are different and specify the suction head possible - you need to check, some need a positive suction head, others can have several metres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually meaning is that if you were to pressurize a sealed container, it would reach that pressure (as long as the seal does not break).  Similarly a maximum flow rate is how much would flow if there were no resistance (pretty much never).

Where there is flow, there is resistance.  The faster you need something to flow (against the walls of something), the greater this resistance.  It is also affected by other factors like the viscosity of the fluid and the diameter of the hose/pipe you are flowing it through.  In other words if it doesn't get the rate you need, make changes to things downstream from the pump.  The literal bottleneck may be that of your target container.  It should be reasonably easy to test the resistance for your setup using gravity instead of a pump, and a stopwatch.  How high (compared to where you'd connect the pump) does your source fed through your pipe need to be to get your 1L filled in 10s?

Whether you need the higher pressure pump will depend on the pressure vs flow curve of the pump - usually it's more than safe enough to assume that you can draw a line from 0 flow and max pressure to 0 head and max flow.  This is because of the shape usually being convex to the 0,0 point.  Take your head from the height experiment (0.0361 psi per inch water), and if your flow on that line is greater than 6L/min you can consider it OK.